# Simple Express program for querying a result

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

### I have a snippet of Express code

Below what i am trying to do is pass the table name to **keyName** by extracting from the request

But I am facing deaslock

**i wanted to know whether i am following proper protocols for JSON response**

**[Part-of-Express-Code]**

```
app.get('/RestaurantDesc/:Key',function(request,response,next){

    var keyName=request.query.Key;
    var name_of_restaurants, RestaurantTimings;
    async.series( [
        // Get the first table contents
        function ( callback ) {
            connection.query('SELECT * FROM ',keyName, function(err, rows, fields)
                {
                        console.log('Connection result error '+err);
                        name_of_restaurants = rows;
                        callback();
                });
        },
        // Get the second table contents
        function ( callback ) {
        connection.query('SELECT * FROM RestaurantTimings', function(err, rows, fields)

            {
                    console.log('Connection result error '+err);
                    RestaurantTimings = rows;
                    callback();
            });
        }

   // Send the response
], function ( error, results ) {
    response.json({
        'restaurants' : name_of_restaurants,
        'RestaurantTimings' : RestaurantTimings
    });
} );
} );
```

I am getting the output as Cannot `GET /RestaurantDesc/`

**Any Ideas**

Comment: Are you passing :Key in your Get request?

Comment: I am passing (key,value) pair as (Key,Aroy) from client..... so i am trying to store Aroy in the variable and pass to the query so based on the value the json response is generated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your route should be path, A path that you can access through GET request. 
for ex: you should be able to access it through

```
http://example.com/RestaurantDesc/anyKeyHere
```

and in your code you have

```
var keyName = request.query.Key
```

req.query contains query variables see http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.query

So your keyName variable won't contain anyKeyHere.

req.params.Key will contain value anyKeyHere;

but you will need to pass it in url path.

if you need to pass key data in query you can do this.

```
app.get('/RestaurantDesc',function(request,response,next){
   var keyName=request.query.Key;
 });
```

and pass key like this in your url

```
http://example.com/RestaurantDesc/?Key=restaurnetkeyHere
```

Try going through guide in express site and understand routings and how it works.

Comment: Your information helped.... i extended your solution .... please look at this link (http://stackoverflow.com/q/18525144/2582071) give your feed back please !

Answer (score 1):

If you getting "Cannot GET `/RestaurantDesc/`" is because you have not setup this route, try `/RestaurantDesc/something`. request.query is used for search terms, ie things that come after a questionmaek in a url. Use request.param.Key instead.

Also for best practices you should lowercase resource names and use the shorter req/res instead of request/response.

Comment: `req` vs. `request` is purely opinion based. Just because most example code uses `req` doesn't mean it fits in with your other naming conventions. I think "best practice" would simply to be consistent within your code base. At my last organization we much preferred parameters which weren't abbreviations, in general, so we used `request` and `response` because it was consistent for us, and made it easier to not confuse the two at a glance.

Comment: What is the main difference b/w  `request.query` and  `request.param` ....... If a Client sends a request as (key,value) pair to server ...... how a server should handle it .... should i use `request.query` or `request.param`

Comment: req.query is for matching key/value pairs that come after a questionmark in a url for example www.mydomain.com/somepath?myquery=test. myquery is the key test is the value. You need to use params as your url does not contain a query.