# req.query and req.param in ExpressJS

Tags: node.js, express

### Main differences between `req.query` and `req.param` in Express

- How are Both different from each other
- When to use then in what cases

***Suppose a client sends say Android (Key,value) pair in the request ........ which one to use ?***

**[EDIT]**

Suppose android sends a POST  request -> Intention is to send (Key,Value) to client and the server should perform a database query based on the value in the server and return JSON response

**Look:: at this question for the program i referenced:**: [Simple Express program for querying a result](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18515313/2582071)

Comment: Do you mean `req.query` and `req.param`?

Comment: yes ! ......... I have modified the question also

Answer (score 170):

`req.query` will return a JS object after the query string is parsed.

*/user?name=tom&age=55* - `req.query` would yield `{name:"tom", age: "55"}`

`req.params` will return parameters in the matched route.
If your route is */user/:id* and you make a request to */user/5* - `req.params` would yield `{id: "5"}`

`req.param` is a function that peels parameters out of the request. All of this can be found [here](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.params).

**UPDATE**

If the verb is a `POST` and you are using `bodyParser`, then you should be able to get the form body in you function with `req.body`. That will be the parsed JS version of the `POST`ed form.

Comment: Thanks, then Suppose a client sends say Android (Key,value) pair in the request ........ which one to use in Express ?

Comment: There is no way to answer this question without seeing the request in question.

Comment: Please look at the updated question ..... i have also mentioned the link to the program i am using in express in one of the questions i posted .....please add a feed back !

Comment: @Iplay if this answer helped you, please consider marking it as the answer to this question. Thanks.

Answer (score 24):

`req.query` is the query string sent to the server, example `/page?`**test=1**, `req.param` is the parameters passed to the handler.

`app.get('/user/:id', handler);`, going to `/user/blah`, `req.param.id` would return `blah`;

Comment: Thanks, then Suppose a client sends say Android (Key,value) pair in the request ........ which one to use ?

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about, if it's a POST request, it will be in the `req.data`, if it's GET t'll be in `req.param`

Comment: Hi, could you please tell me how to check req.params against undefined?

Comment: @AnandRaj it would be just empty, so check `c.Param("id") == ""`

Comment: sorry for this. what is "c" here? is it req.params?

Comment: @OneOfOne This is incorrect. `req.param` is a function, it is *not* _"the parameters passed to the handler"_. That's `req.params`

Answer (score 18):

I would suggest using  following

```
req.param('<param_name>')
```

req.param("") works as following

Lookup is performed in the following order:

```
req.params
req.body
req.query
```

Direct access to req.body, req.params, and req.query should be favoured for clarity - unless you truly accept input from each object.

Ref:http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#req.param

Comment: Hi, could you please tell me how to check req.params against undefined?

Comment: @AnandRaj what do you mean by undefined? do you mean params are not  known?

Comment: what i meant is when i checked the type of req.params it shows undefined . My goal is to check whether req.params.<any URI parameter> is null or not

Comment: @AnandRaj can you please post your code? Following code works for me         var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  console.log(req.params);
  res.send(req.params);
});

app.listen(3000);

Comment: @AnandRaj try if(reqParams.hasOwnProperty('deviceType')){

}

Answer (score 13):

Passing params

```
GET request to "/cars/honda"
```

returns a list of Honda car models

Passing query

```
GET request to "/car/honda?color=blue"
```

returns a list of Honda car models, 
but filtered so only models with an stock color of blue are returned.

It doesn't make sense to add those filters into the URL parameters (/car/honda/color/blue) because according to REST, that would imply that we want to get a bunch of information about the color "blue". Since what we really want is a filtered list of Honda models, we use query strings to filter down the results that get returned.

Notice that the query strings are really just { key: value } pairs in a slightly different format: ?key1=value1&key2=value2&key3=value3.