# Replacement for req.param() that is deprecated in Express 4

Tags: node.js, express

We are migrating from ExpressJS 3 to ExpressJS 4, and we noted that the following APIs are being deprecated:

```
req.param(fieldName)
req.param(fieldName, defaultValue)
```

Is there a middleware that brings these APIs back, like other APIs that were 'externalized' from express to independent modules ?

EDITED:
Clarification - The need is an API that provides an abstracted generic access to a parameter, regardless to if it is a path-parameter, a query-string parameter, or a body field.

Comment: If you came from search engine FUT -> [2nd answer in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18524125/request-query-and-request-param-in-expressjs)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, after reading the threads given in references by @Ineentho, we decided to come up with the following answer:

https://github.com/osher/request-param

> A connect/express middleware to enable back the req.param(name,default) API deprecated in express 4

The middleware does not only brings back the goo'old functionality. 
It also lets you ***customize the order of collections from which params are retrieved*** , both as default rule, and as per-call :-)

Have fun!

Comment: Thanks for contributing your solution to the web as a middleware! Even if I would think your case is a edge case, somebody else will probably also benefint from this module

Answer (score 17):

Based on Express Documentation, we should use like this

On [express 3](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.param)

```
req.param(fieldName)
```

On [express 4](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.params)

```
req.params.fieldName
```

Personally i prefer `req.params.fieldName` instead `req.param(fieldName)`

Comment: Please notice that they are not equal, req.param checks req.params, req.body and req.query. See my answer for details.

Comment: `req.params.fieldName`doesn't work with `?=&` url style... `req.param()` still does.

Comment: @sekti92 - you're not answering the question. The question origninally asks about an API that provided a generic way to access them both.

Answer (score 11):

Why would you want to bring it back? There's a reason that it's been deprecated and as such you should probably move away from it.

The discussion on why they are deprecating the API is available at their issue tracker as [#2440](https://github.com/strongloop/express/issues/2440).

The function is a quick and dirty way to get a parameter value from either `req.params`, `req.body` or `req.query`. This could of course cause trouble in some cases, which is why they are removing it. See the function for yourself [here](https://github.com/strongloop/express/blob/dee9fbbbda2f2483c657cf912f68db1a5ba1fcac/lib/request.js#L203).

If you are just using the function for url parameters, you can just replace it with this a check for `req.query['smth'] or 'default'`:

```
var param_old = req.param('test', 'default');
var param_new = req.query['test'] || 'default';
```

(Please note that an empty string is evaluated to `false`, so they are not actually 100% equal. What you want is of course up to you, but for the most part it shouldn't matter.)

Comment: Nope, I'm using it for instrumentation that serves different handlers that in deed may expect their parameters as param, OR query string OR body parameters. In this - the function did exactly what I wanted. Thanks for the answer and the references

Comment: Oh okey, well in that case it might make sense. I still hope that this answer can help people who where using it for just the query parameters.

Comment: Yea, I think I agree. Maybe we should add in the README.md a note about this pitfall

Comment: Thank you so much you saved my time ..

:)

Comment: This answer suggests that most of express.js users are incompetent amateurs, right? They do not read the docs and they can't be responsible for the security of their own apps. This is insulting - downvote, sir. A very useful function was indeed deprecated for ridiculous reasons.

Comment: I'm sorry if I worded myself badly, or if I'm missing something here, but I don't see many practical usecases for this function. If somebody is using this function it's likely that they used it because they thought that it only returned one of the things it returns. For example somebody may be using this for only query parameters not realizing it could find it in the body as well.