# Express req.param deprecated syntax

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

On Node.js I am getting this error, in some JavaScript code:

```
express deprecated req.param(name): Use req.params, req.body,
```

Here is the relevant code:

```
  response.render('pages/' + displayPage, {
    MYVAR: request.param('MYVAR'),
    MYVAR2: request.MYVAR,
    MYVAR3: request.params.MYVAR
  });
```

In other words this line is deprecated

```
   MYVAR: request.param('MYVAR'),
```

But, it does the job (at least for now).

And the other type of syntax I tried, by guessing or by finding on the net after searching, all failed.
Including these lines:

```
MYVAR2: request.MYVAR,
MYVAR3: request.params.MYVAR
```

and a few more options that would be pointless to list here.
So the question is: what is the right syntax to use?

***Here is some more information, added by editing the post after reading some comments:***

I send the request parameters this way:

```
https://myapp.herokuapp.com/branch?MYVAR=64.39
```

Inside index.js the code processing the /branch is:

```
response.render('pages/' + displayPage, {
  MYVAR: request.param('MYVAR'),
  MYVAR2: request.params.MYVAR,
  MYVAR3: request.params['MYVAR']
});
```

Inside the branch.ejs file I have placed the following in order to see what I am getting:

```
<body bgcolor=#221122E>
<b>MYVAR=<%= MYVAR %></b><br/>
<b>MYVAR2=<%= MYVAR2 %></b><br/>
<b>MYVAR3=<%= MYVAR3 %></b><br/>
......
```

And finally this is what I can see in the browser, displayed by branch.ejs:

```
MYVAR=64.39
MYVAR2=
MYVAR3=
```

It shows that the variable passed with the old syntax arrives as expected, but not the other ones.

Comment: "Failed"... how? Is this a `POST` or `GET` request? What's the url?

Comment: "But, it does the job (at least for now)" But it probably wont't for very much longer. check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28949266/replacement-for-req-param-that-is-deprecated-in-express-4

Comment: I think its request.params.MYVAR

Comment: Doesn't the message already clearly state what to use now? `Use req.params, req.body`

Comment: The docs say `Deprecated. Use either req.params, req.body or req.query, as applicable.` You just need to figure out the proper one. We could help, but we don't have enough information.

Comment: After reading all the comments and answers, I have edited the post, adding some information at the end. I hope this will make things clearer and help find out what I am missing.

Answer (score 2):

Which of the variants is needed depends on how you send request parameters:

- You need to use `req.query.MYVAR` if your request uses the `GET` method with parameters after the `?` like `/path?MYVAR=123`.
- If you have your parameters in the path (e.g. `/path/:MYVAR` in your express `get` call), `req.params.MYVAR` is correct.
- If you use `POST` or `PUT`, you need to use `req.body.MYVAR`, because of the data is transferred in the body. Since express doesn't parse the body , you need to include and use an additional package like [body-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using:

```
request.param('MYVAR')
```

You are supposed to use:

```
request.params['MYVAR']
// Or this:
request.params.MYVAR
```