# Why was req.param() deprecated in Express 4?

Tags: express

I understand what the deprecation implies, but as of the why, the only answer I found is that

> [It was dumb [...] Stomping out those weird CGI-isms :) People would
> just access properties in req.params, req.body or req.query.](https://github.com/expressjs/expressjs.com/issues/314)

(What are CGI-isms?)

Was it a performance issue, or just a matter of making things clearer?

Answer (score -1):

app.use('/public/vendorInfo/:id', (req, res) => {

```
const vatImage = req.param('vat_image');

res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/vendorInfo/', id)
```

});

Answer (score -2):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28949933/5941620) pointed me in the right direction, the discussion which led to the deprecation can be found here: https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/2440

In a nutshell, not using req.param() makes the source of parameters obvious and misusing the function could lead to security issues:

> Namely, they were using req.param('key') to get key from the body, but
>   little did they realize, it checked the query as well. This allowed
>   for XSS attacks really easily by remote sites embedding  and
>   similar.