# Redirect to home page on login with username appended in url

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest

I want to know when a user logs in successfully onto Facebook he is redirected to home page with its first name and last name being part of the url.
How is that process being carried out and how to do the same using nodejs.

```
var checkSession=require('./../custom-modules/sessionManager');
var express=require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var builtLoginMaster=require('./../custom-modules/BuiltLoginMaster');
var scripts=require('./../cdnscripts.json');//cdn scripts

//handle login authentication
router.post('/logincheck',function(req,res,next){
    console.log("got hit on authenticate url");
    var session=req.session;
    var email  = req.body.email;
    var pass   = req.body.password;
    builtLoginMaster.authenticateUser(email,pass,function(object){
        if(object!==null)
        {

            console.log('Rendering chat page and result');
            console.log("setting session");
            // console.log(session);
            session.user=object.toJSON();//set user object in session           
            //here home page 
            //here only home page rendered with same '/logincheck' whereas i want something "http://example.com/firstname.lastname"
            res.render('home',{title:"Twiddle",
                                url:scripts,
                                user:object.toJSON()});
        }
        else{
                session.err="Invalid credentials";
            }
    });

});
//=============================Root file===========================
router.get('/',checkSession,function(req,res,next){

    console.log("after checked session");
    console.log(req.session);
    if(!req.isLoggedIn)
    {   
        console.log('user not logged in');
        res.render('login',{ title:'Login Page',
                         url:scripts,
                         session:req.session});

    }
    else
    {
            res.render('home',{title:"Twiddle",
                                url:scripts,
                                user:req.session})  ;
            console.log("redirect to home");
    }
    });

router.get('/register',function(req,res,next){

    res.render('register',{ title:'Registration',
                            url:scripts});
});
router.get('/test',function(req,res,next){
    res.render('test',{ title:'test',
                            url:scripts});
});


module.exports = router;
```

Comment: So instead of `res.render(..` you want to do `res.redirect('/'+user.fname+'.'+user.lname)`

Comment: yup!!so that on home page the link will be http://example.com/username

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
res.render('home...
```

what you wanna do instead is

```
res.redirect('/user/' + user.username);
```

<sub>Note, you should use `/user/:username` instead of just `/:username` because that could get tricky and handling that kind of "unified" path would not be very efficient. You'll essentially be querying the database on ***every*** request `/xyz` to check whether `xyz` is a valid user/name or just another path.</sub>

Now from the `/logincheck` you assigned the user object in `session` so it'll be available in `req.session.user` on each new request. So you can in a way just continue on from there.

You then want to define the path `/user/:username`

```
app.get('/user/:username', function(req, res, next){

    // Here, if you don't want just anybody to view this page, you can verify
    if(req.session.user.username != req.params.username) return res.status(401).send('Unauthorized!');

    // Then continue to render whatever you like
    res.render('home',{title:"Twiddle", user:req.session.user});
});
```

Some resources for more info on the following:
[`req.session`](http://blog.modulus.io/nodejs-and-express-sessions),
[`req.params`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18524125/request-query-and-request-param-in-expressjs)

Comment: thanx thats very precise answer!!