# Read nested json body param in Express

Tags: json, node.js, express

I want to read the param nested in json body in `express.js`, however I am able to read the first level of params in the body:

```
{
  "name": "foo",
  "address": {
    "zip": "3008"
  }
}
```

So if I do:

```
req.param('name')
```

I get the value `foo;`
but I am not able to fetch the value of `zip`. Can someone help me with that ?

I have used:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // support json encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // support encoded bodies
```

Answer (score 1):

`req.param()` is deprecated

You can use `req.body` instead.

In this case `req.body` will get the **entire object** and `req.body.address` will get the **zip code object**

API docs on [req.param()](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.param) method

API docs on [req.body](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.body) object

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18524191/3359432) will be usefull

Comment: I want something like req.body.zip or req.params.zip should give me 3000

Comment: You can get it as I told my answer. Just say var zip = req.body.adddress.zip;