# post request not taking in data - express js and mongo

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am using this code:

```
app.post("/users", function(req, res) {
db.collection(USERS_COLLECTION).insertOne(req.body , function(err, doc) {
if (err) {
  handleError(res, err.message, "Failed to create new user.");
} else {
  res.status(201).json(req.body);
 }
  });
});
```

and I am trying putting in this request: localhost:8080/users?firstName=foo&lastName=bar

but when I try the post request in postman it returns just an id and doesn't insert the params in the database.

```
{
    "_id": "584f04eb141faa7df7fc4059"
}
```

how do I fix this so that it returns the data or do I need to create a schema first and check against it? If I could be pointed in the right direction that would be great

Answer (score 1):

You're correct in that you need a schema!

If there were no schema in a database, you essentially would have a bucket full of (potentially) mismatched JSON objects. Thus, it would be tedious to ensure that your keys match up to their expected values.

If you're new to Mongo, I'd recommend checking out [Mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/) ODM. It helps when trying to understand the structure and quirks of a NoSQL DB.

Comment: ok cool. So how to implement it with my current logic once I create the schema.. how do I inspect the params in the url to lineup with the schema

Comment: I don't have enough of your code to be 100% sure, but if you define the schema and run what you had in your example, it should be good to go. Mongo runs outside of your application (this is why you type `mongod` in your terminal before running), so when you add entries, it should know without you having to do anything else.

Comment: check below please

Answer (score 1):

ok.. So I created a Schema

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

// user schema
var usersSchema = mongoose.Schema({

   firstName: String,
   lastName : String,
   email : String
});

mongoose.model('users', usersSchema);
```

and the post request code looks like this:

```
var express = require("express");
var path = require("path");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var mongodb = require("mongodb");
var ObjectID = mongodb.ObjectID;
var USERS_COLLECTION = "users";
var mongoURL = "the url is here";
var user = require("./Models/User");
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
app.use(bodyParser.json());


app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
   extended: true
}));

mongoose.connect(mongoURL);

// USERS API ROUTES BELOW

// Generic error handler used by all endpoints.
function handleError(res, reason, message, code) {
   console.log("ERROR: " + reason);
   res.status(code || 500).json({"error": message});
}

 /*  "/USERS"
  *    POST: creates a new user
 */

app.post("/users", function(req, res) {

  var firstName = req.params.firstName;
  var lastName = req.params.lastName;
  var email = req.params.email;

//call the create function for our database
 mongoose.model('users').create({
   firstName : firstName,
   lastName : lastName,
   email : email
 }, function (err, user) {
 if (err) {
  res.send("There was a problem adding the information to the database.");
  } else {
   //User has been created
    console.log('POST creating new users: ' + user + firstName);
    res.format({
      //JSON response will show the newly created user
      json: function(){
      res.json(user);
      }
    });
    }
  })
});
```

though the issue is that when I send a http post request :

```
localhost:8080/users?firstName=foo&lastName=bar&email=foobar@gmail.com
```

req.body.firstName = undefined and req.params.firstName = undefined how do I get it to properly read in the values? When I put static strings in the place of req.body... it works perfect.

this is what returns in json currently:

```
{
   "__v": 0,
   "_id": "5851567048018fa141543f53"
}
```

Comment: Cool, you're on the right track. Looks like you forgot an `=`. `&lastNamebar&email=foo` -> `&lastName=bar&email=foo`. If that's not it, `npm install -s body-parser` and put `server.use(bodyParser.json())` wherever you're keeping your middleware.

Comment: How do i access them.in the parameters

Comment: They're in the URL: `localhost:8080/users?firstName=foo&lastName=bar&email=foobar@gmail.com` will yield `req.params.firstName`, `req.params.lastName`, and `req.params.email`

Comment: Its still coming up undefined when I try to access it through params, and I have bodyparser already and I fixed the url and it still doesnt work.. i have updated my code above to show you the whole code so you can help me figure out another way to approach this fix.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that the syntax is different for POST. You can get the parameters with `req.query`. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18524125/request-query-and-request-param-in-expressjs) post explains the difference well.

Answer (score 0):

21 things matter the most on this problem

1. you do not implement a body-parser
   here you can install it by: npm I body-parser

```
app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

2. add content type in postman if you use postman to send API
   Content-Type: application/JSON

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, and Thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code? Pls read [how-to-answer guideline](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)