# Creating dynamic link by requesting data from front-end in Node.js and Express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

This is kind of hard for me to explain but I am trying to shorten my code by creating one link instead of 50 for downloading a form. I will try to explain this a bit better using my code.

I have 5 get requests that do exactly the same thing but download a different file.

```
router.get('/form1', function (req, res) {
    var file = __dirname + '/../public/forms/form1.pdf';
    res.download(file);
});

router.get('/form2', function (req, res) {
    var file = __dirname + '/../public/forms/form2.pdf';
    res.download(file); 
});
etc...
```

and my front-end link are;

```
<a href="/downloads/form1">FORM 1</a>
<a href="/downloads/form2">FORM 2</a>
etc...
```

Is there anything I can do to make this a more dynamic? The only way I can think of is something like this;

```
router.get('/:formName', function (req, res) {
    // some how do a "req.params.formName" 
    var file = __dirname + '/../public/forms/' + req.params.formName + '.pdf';
    res.download(file); // Set disposition and send it.
});
```

But I don't know how I will get the formName or if thats even possible.

Comment: Your code looks  correct to me... do you get an error?

Comment: @DavidEspino The code is correct except for the last part since there is no "formName" to request from the front-end. I can't just have 5 different <a> tag with formName can i?

Comment: ... I'm a bit confused, I thought you were leaving your `<a>` elements, just refactoring your controller functions. If you click on that, and assuming that method is in the `downloads controller`, clicking on `<a href="/downloads/form1">FORM 1</a>` should take you to that function... if you want your ui to be dynamic, that's another story. You may need a templating language...

Comment: @DavidEspino No no, you're right. I'm just trying to refactor my controller function. How would `<a href="/downloads/form1">FORM 1</a>` work if the controller is  `router.get('/:formName', function (req, res) { ...`? How is it supposed to know what :formName is?

Comment: https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req

Comment: You can try to use a query string `<a href="/downloads?form=form1">FORM 1</a>`, then you can easily access the query string from your code
`console.log(req.query.form)`

Comment: The `:paramName` works as a place holder for your params. If you add two params... you could have `/:param1/:param2`, and get them from the `req.params` dictionary

Comment: @E.deSaintChamas I just get an error with `Cannot GET /downloads?form=form1`

Comment: If you use downloads?form=form1 you have to use req.query.form. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18524125/request-query-and-request-param-in-expressjs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some more options to clarify:

- Option 1: If you have a folder on the server with a fairly manageable directory structure, simply use **express.static** to map the physical folder to a virtual one with automatic download:

  ```
  app.use('/download', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public/forms/')))
  ```

  This will result in any link from the front-end with **href='/download/something.pdf'** working as long as that file is on the server in the path you mapped (i.e. in /public/forms).
- Option 2 (which David E above answered in essence): In your original code, if you wanted to generate a path handler for a link that looks like /download/form1, /download/form2, it's a very minor modification:

  ```
  router.get('/download/:formNumber', function (req, res) {
      var file = __dirname + '/public/forms/' + req.params.formNumber + '.pdf';
      res.download(file);
  });
  ```
- Option 3: You want to authenticate access to the files and potentially support multiple, complex URL schemes to a single handler that can lookup the appropriate physical path and send the file:

  ```
  router.get('/download/:path[forms|images|files]/:formNumber1', fileRequestHandler);
  router.get('/public/downloadFolder2/:formNumber2', fileRequestHandler);
  router.get('/public/downloadFolder3/:formNumber3', fileRequestHandler);
  function fileRequestHandler(req, res) {
      // Check authentication here - example below from Passport
      if(!req.isAuthenticated()) 
          return res.status(401).send({err: 'Unauthorized'});

      // Check which form number is supplied and map to appropriate physical file
      if(req.params.formNumber1) {
          // in this example, req.params.path can be one of three allowed sample values - forms or images or files
          var file = __dirname + '/public/' + req.params.path + '/' + req.params.formNumber + '.pdf';
          res.download(file);
      } else if(req.params.formNumber2) {
          // etc.
      }
  }
  ```

Note: **Ezra Chang's point about path validity is important.**

Comment: That's perfect. I'm using Option 2 and it works like I wanted to. I just don't understand how `req.params.formNumber` is working. How does it know to choose the params from `<a href="/downloads/form1">` and not something else? I will have a look into the documentation to try understand this better but your answer covered everything I need to know so far.

Comment: Notice the colon (:) in front of the word formNumber? That's what makes the Express router treat the second half of the URL as a variable. So using /download/:variableName will match any incoming request that begins with the word `download` (that's a static match), followed by a `/` and then ANY other word. As long as you don't confuse the router by giving something too similar to distinguish, it can setup a routing table to pattern match incoming requests.

Comment: Thanks. I perfectly understand it now and this opened up so much more options for me and I don't have to repeat a lot of my code.

Answer (score 1):

This response assumes that your route lives in `index.js`.

```
router.get('/form/:formName', (req, res, next) => {
  res.download(`${__dirname}/../public/forms/${req.params.formName}.pdf`);
});

<a href="/form/form2">FORM 2</a>
```

Be careful about your path. I don't know whether you can start at a directory, go up a level, then down again.