# ExpressJS request.params and request.body empty

Tags: node.js, express

Trying to send a simple post request, the `body` property is empty object `{}`. Anyone knows why?

```
const compression = require('compression')
const bodyParser  = require('body-parser')
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.set('port', process.env.PORT)

// Support JSON-encoded and encoded bodies.
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

app.post('/api/' + APIVersion.latest() + '/post-job', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body)
  res.json({ hey: 'hey' })
})

// Start the server.
app.listen(app.get('port'), err => {
  if (err) {
    return console.log('There was an error', err)
  }

  console.log(`Server running on port ${app.get('port')}`)
})
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Request.query and Request.param in ExpressJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18524125/request-query-and-request-param-in-expressjs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`req.params` is empty because your route doesn't specify any.

In `Express`, `params` refers to the route/url parameters. For example, if you wanted to have a route that allowed you to dynamically specify a user's last name, you may do:

```
app.get('/users/:last/info', (req, res) => {
    // ....
})
```

This would give the route a parameter of `last`, accessible by `req.params.last`.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense! Any tips why the body isn't displayed? Is the request correct based on the httpbin response?

Comment: `req.body` will be empty as well if you pass the data through the query system

Comment: I have now removed those lines, will update the example. Tried sending a request from hurl.it, still the same result unfortunately.

Comment: are you using javascript to request routes on your api?

Comment: If you're referring to the `APIVersion.latest()` part, yes, it only returns string `v0.1`

Comment: No. What are you using to send HTTP requests to your api

Comment: I use `Fetch API`, but also tried to make a manual request from `https://www.hurl.it`

Comment: My man, just figured it out! I had incorrectly passed headers to the request! Thank you very much! (Been coding for a while today haha)

Answer (score 0):

`req.params` holds the [**route** params](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html), e.g. for `/users/:id`:

```
GET /users/123
req.params.id = 123
```

You want to access `req.query`, if you requested `/api/v1/post-job?test=value`, or the body itself in case you posted any.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense! Any tips why the body isn't displayed? Is the request correct based on the httpbin response?

Answer (score 0):

If req.body isn't being populated, you'll need to check how you are sending your POST request, since req.body is completely separate from the URL. If it's in an HTML form:

```
<form action="/person" method="POST">
  <input name="firstName" type="text">
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

If you're sending your requests through a different avenue, you'll have to check the documentation for that API.