# Express JS routing parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I need to use the data from quote_number parameter to create a query from this url:

http://localhost:3000/#/quote/line/?quote_number=1003

where `quote_number = ${req.params.quote_number}`

I'm expecting to get `1003` from this, but am getting `line` as the return parameter

Answer (score 1):

The URL is not correct. Because you have the # symbol, Nothing is recognized after  that. I don't know if you're doing it because there's no additional code.

If you try like this:

```
app.get('/quote/line/:id', (req, res) =>{
    console.log(req.params);
});
```

URL in browser:

```
http://localhost:3000/quote/line/quote_number=1003
```

result:

```
{ quote_number: 'quote_number=1003' }
```

if you use `query` instead of `params`:

```
app.get('/quote/line/', (req, res) =>{
    console.log(req.query);
});
```

in browser:

```
http://localhost:3000/quote/line/?quote_number=1003
```

result:

```
{ quote_number: '1003' }
```

and now, you can get the value by

```
req.query.quote_number
```

References:

[req.query and req.param in ExpressJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18524125/req-query-and-req-param-in-expressjs)

Comment: It's not just that express doesn't recognise anything after `#` (if that's the case you can manually parse the url yourself) but the browser does not send anything after the `#` back to the server