# How do I search for a data in the database with Node JS, Postgres, and dust js

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, postgresql

I'm making a webpage with Node JS with dustjs and PostgreSQL. How do I make a search query in the html, so I can pass the value to the app.get
Do I need to use JQuery?

```
app.get('/teachers', function(req, res){
  pool.connect(function(err, client, done){
    if(err) {
      return console.error("error", err);
    }
    client.query('SELECT * FROM teachers', function(err, result){
      if(err){
        return console.error('error running query', err)
      }
      res.render('teacherindex', {teachers: result.rows});
      done();
    });
  });
});



app.get('/teachers/:str', (req,res)=>{
  pool.connect((err, client, done) => {
    if (err) throw err
    client.query('SELECT * FROM teachers WHERE name = $1', [req.query.namesearch], (err, result) => {
      done()
      if (err) {
        console.log(err.stack)
      } else {
        res.render('teacherindex', {teachers: result.rows});
      }
    })
  })
})
```

This is my JQuery

```
$("#myBtn").click(function(){
    var str = $("#myInput").val();
    var url = '/teachers/'+str;
    if(confirm('Search Record?')){
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'put',
            success: function(result){
                console.log('Searching');
                window.location.href='/teachers';
            },
            error: function(err){
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

My HTML

```
<input type="text" id="myInput" data-id="namesearch">
<button type="button" id="myBtn">Show Value</button>
```

Thank you!

Comment: At a high level glance, it appears you are doing this correctly. Sending AJAX from the client to your server. Your server retrieves results based upon what the client sent, and responds with those results. Are you getting an error? What prompted you to post this question?

Comment: Only thing I can see from a high level is if there is an error you aren't responding back to the client, you're just logging the error to console. You should have some type of error handling response, otherwise the browser is most likely just spinning forever waiting for a response from your server.

Comment: Yes, I'm still getting an error. I cannot retrieve the value from input text box to the server. I'm working on a college project by the way

Comment: I went ahead and updated my answer with everything that I found. Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***FINAL ANSWER:***

Ok so it turns out the issue you were having was something completely different. You are trying to use server side rendering for this, and I was showing you how to render the retrieved data on the client side.

I have forked, and updated your repo - which can be found at the link below..

Please review my changes and let me know if you have any questions.

Working repo: https://github.com/oze4/hanstanawi.github.io

Demo Video: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/oze4/hanstanawi.github.io/master/fake_uni_demo.mp4

[image]

---

---

---

***EDIT:***

[I went ahead and built a repository to try and help you grasp these concepts. You can find the repo here](https://github.com/oze4/node-jquery-example) - I tried to keep things as simple and understandable as possible, but let me know if you have any questions.

- I had to make some minor changes to the paths, which I have commented explanations on the code in the repo.
- I am using a "mock" database (just a JSON object in a different file) but the logic remains the same.
- The [`index.js`](https://github.com/oze4/node-jquery-example/blob/master/index.js) is the main entry point and contains all route data.
- The [`index.html`](https://github.com/oze4/node-jquery-example/blob/master/index.html) file is what gets sent to the user, and is the main HTML file, which contains the `jQuery` code.

If you download/fork/test out the code in that repo, open up your browsers developer tools, go to the network tab, and check out the differences.

***Using `req.params`***

[image]

***Using `req.query`***

[image]

---

---

---

***ORIGINAL ANSWER:***

So there are a couple of things wrong with your code and why you are unable to see the value of the textbox server side.

- You are sending a `PUT` request but your server is expecting a `GET` request
- You are looking for the value in `req.query` when you should be looking for it in `req.params`
- You are looking for the incorrect variable name in your route (on top of using query when you should be using params) `req.query.namesearch` needs to be `req.params.str`
- [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18524125/req-query-and-req-param-in-expressjs) for more on `req.query` vs `req.params`

> ***More detailed examples below.***

- ***In your route you are specifying `app.get` - in other words, you are expecting a `GET` request to be sent to your server..*** but your are sending a `PUT` request..
- If you were sending your `AJAX` to your server by using something like `/teachers?str=someName` then you would use `req.query.str` - or if you wanted to use `namesearch` you would do: `/teachers?namesearch=someName` and then to get the value: `req.query.namesearch`
- If you send your `AJAX` to your server by using the something like `/teachers/someName` then you should be using `req.params.str`

```
//  ||
//  \/ Server is expecting a GET request
app.get('/teachers/:str', (req, res) => {
  // GET THE CORRECT VALUE
  let namesearch = req.params.str;

  pool.connect((err, client, done) => {
    // ... other code here

    client.query(
      'SELECT * FROM teachers WHERE name = $1',

      // SPECIFY THE CORRECT VALUE
      namesearch,

      (err, result) => {
        // ... other code here
      })
  })
});
```

- ***But in your `AJAX` request, you are specifying `PUT`.. (should be `GET`)***
- By default, `AJAX` will send `GET` requests, so you really don't have to specify any `type` here, but I personally like to specify `GET` in `type`, just for the sake of brevity - just more succinct in my opinion.
- Again, specifying `GET` in `type` is ***not*** needed since `AJAX` sends `GET` by default, specifying `GET` in `type` is a matter of preference.

```
$("#myBtn").click(function () {
  // ... other code here
  let textboxValue = $("#myTextbox").val();
  let theURL = "/teachers/" + textboxValue;

  // OR if you wanted to use `req.query.str` server side
  // let theURL = "/teachers?str=" + textboxValue;

  if (confirm('Search Record?')) {
    $.ajax({
      url: theURL,
      //     ||
      //     \/ You are sending a PUT request, not a GET request
      type: 'put', // EITHER CHANGE THIS TO GET OR JUST REMOVE type
      // ... other code here
    });
  }
});
```

It appears you are grabbing the value correctly from the textbox, you just need to make sure your server is accepting the same type that you are sending.

Comment: I have tried your method, but still don't get any result. In your code, what does req.params.str refer to? In your jquery code, there's no str variable. Sorry, I'm still pretty new in node js

Comment: The Node code isn't aware/doesn't know about anything jQuery related. Anything jQuery related is running in the persons browser that visits your website. The `str` refers to the variable in your route. `app.get('/teacher/:str)...` the `/:str` part means that is a variable.

Comment: I'm still getting no result. But the server doesn't give out any error.
What you should I put on the success part of the ajax?

success: function(result){
                    console.log('Searching');
                    window.location.href='/teachers';
                }

Comment: I check the chrome console, it says Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: I would need to see more of your code to help diagnose something like that - it's sounds like you are still sending PUT using ajax versus using GET.

Comment: @Hans I updated my answer with some demo code I wrote. Hopefully this will help in some manner.

Comment: This is my repo for the project, if you like to see my full code
https://github.com/hanstanawi/University-Database-College-Project
The teacher file is the teacherindex and teacherlayout.dust and the js file is teachermain.js

Thank you so much

Comment: It seems I still have problems with rendering the searched results into the html

Comment: I'm going to take a look at your code here in a minute.

Comment: @Hans the only difficult part is I don't have the same data in my database that you do. Did they give you any postgresql commands that build the database? How did you get the data?

Comment: @Hans I have resolved this issue - please see my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. Really appreciate it! Wish you all good luck in your future works. I have learned a lot

Comment: I appreciate your kind words :) They do not go unnoticed. I'm happy I could help, good luck with everything a well!