# firebase functions using expressjs routes get parameters undefined

Tags: typescript, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions

I want to use firebase functions to host my expressjs webapp, however all get parameters seem undefined. Whats the problem?

```
    import functions= require("firebase-functions");
    import admin= require("firebase-admin");
    import express= require("express");
    import bodyParser= require("body-parser");
    const app: express.Application = express();
    admin.initializeApp();

    app.get("/getstory", async (req,resp)=>{
        try{
            const preferred_storyid=req.params.preferred_storyid;
            console.log(`preferred_storyid ${preferred_storyid}`) //logs preferred_storyid undefined. Why?
resp.send("ok");
        }catch (e) {
            resp.send(`erequest_story. ${e}`);
        }
    });
    const faststoryapi = functions.https.onRequest(app);
    module.exports={faststoryapi}
```

Then the code is deployed with

```
firebase deploy --only functions
```

and get request sent by post man
[image]

PS: I have noticed that i cant have more than one route eg i cant have more than one post end point or else the second one is not called. How do you guys do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
...
app.get(async (req,resp) => { // no need of path
    try{
        const preferred_storyid=req.params.preferred_storyid;
        console.log(`preferred_storyid ${preferred_storyid}`) //logs preferred_storyid undefined. Why?
        resp.send("ok");
    } catch (e) {
        resp.send(`erequest_story. ${e}`);
    }
});

const faststoryapi = functions.https.onRequest(app);
module.exports={faststoryapi}
```

Now you can use your function by hitting the url: `https://us-central1-<project-id>.cloudfunctions.net/faststoryapi`. The api endpoint will be same as your exported function name, so you can change your function name accordingly.

If you are hosting an express app in cloud function you need to use `req.query` for url params.
Also in express `req.params` is used for paths like these:

> Route path: /users/:userId/books/:bookId
>   Request URL: http://localhost:3000/users/34/books/8989
>   req.params: { "userId": "34", "bookId": "8989" }

So, what you are looking for is `req.query`.
See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18524191/9321755) for more info

Comment: btw, actually you can have a whole express app in one cloud function, my bad. realised that just today when I tried it myself.

Answer (score 0):

In Firebase Functions  `req` and `res` objects are the same than ExpressJS's. 
To get query params you must use `req.query.xxxx`, while `req.params.xxxx` can be used to access *path params*.