# get filtered products from the same route. Node, Mongoose, MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a database with a product list made with models.

In the route:

```
router.get('/products', (req, res) => {

})
```

I have the complete unfiltered product list.

I want to filter the products by name, color, price and tags and take them out to the front-end.
and the request to the server would be like this:

GET
localhost: 3000/products?name=laptop&color=black&price=400&tags=tech

how to get filtered product data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you've mentioned request url and route which handle that request then also ask that `What would be the requests that I have to make to the router to filter?`
it means that you want to know how to get filtered product data from route handler.

```
 router.get('/products', (req, res) => {
//I assume that your product model is 'Product'
const filteredProduct=Product.find(req.query);
})
```

Please refer above sample route handler which handle both request

```
GET localhost: 3000/products?name=laptop&color=black&price=400&tags=tech     //get filtered product
GET localhost: 3000/products/                    //get all product
```

here i assume that Product is your data model so to get all product record you need to call find() mongoose method without any parameter and to get filtered data,pass object to find method.for example you want all product filter by name,color

```
Product.find({name:'laptop',color:'black'})
```

[req.Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18524125/req-query-and-req-param-in-expressjs) will return a JS object after the query string is parsed.
read more about [req.Query](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.query),[req.params](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.params),[req.body](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.body)

Comment: if this answer solve your question [accept and upvote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, this help me a lot!