# axios get res.data = null

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, axios

I've had a blockage since last night and I still don't understand, let me explain.
I use React, Mongo DB, and NodeJs, and axios for my API calls
I created a route to retrieve the info of a user, when I test the route with PostMan, I have the user info so everything works as it should, only when I make the api call from my front, my res.data returns "null", so I think it's coming from my api call, but I can't find what's wrong.
I am attaching some screenshot, thank you in advance:

API call :

```
 function Post() {


    axios({
        method: "get", url: "http://localhost:4000/api/auth", credentials: true,
        
        params: {
            userId: "62f045f5253a960077a8ff3f"
        }
    })
        .then((res) => {

            console.log(res);


        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });


}
```

Function back getOneUser:

```
exports.getOneUser = (req, res, next) => {
userModel.findOne({_id: req.params.userId}).select('-password -email')
    .then(post => res.status(200).json(post))
    .catch(error => res.status(404).json({error}))
```

}

Comment: Please don't post pictures/screenshots of the code, rather copy & paste them into the question.

Comment: When you check the _Network_ tab in the developer console, what do you see as a response to this particular request?

Comment: I have a status code : 200 OK, I don't understand why when I simulate an api call with postman it works correctly. thanks for the responsiveness

Comment: What is the response for that request?

Comment: With Postman? the response is a json object: {
      "_id": "62f045f5253a960077a8ff3f",
      "name": "Long live",
      "first name": "Tony",
      "nickname": "LeBlond",
      "isAdmin": false,
      "createdAt": "2022-08-07T23:08:37.911Z",
      "updatedAt": "2022-08-07T23:08:37.911Z",
      "__v": 0
}                                                                                                                                                               Sorry i'm beginner

Comment: If you click the response in the Network tab of the developer console, you should be able to navigate to a 'Response' tab, showing the response as your browser received it. Is this null?

Comment: Yes that's right

Comment: Alright, this is because you can't send `body` with `GET` request. In Postman it does work but with Javascript it won't work. Send it as query params.

Comment: So I modified my code (you can see it on my post that I modified), but I still have an answer: null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In express, use `req.query` instead of `req.params`.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18524125/req-query-and-req-param-in-expressjs) might clarify the differences between them

Comment: Thanks that's what I'm missing to get this to work, thanks so much everyone for the help!