# axios sends an empty json postman sends data

Tags: node.js, axios

I have a little problem that I do not understand I use nodejs and react on the front side I was able to test all my api with postman but when I try to call a route in get on the front side my back returns me empty.

Cross origin nodejs :

```js
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content, Accept, Content-Type, Authorization"
  );
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
    "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS"
  );
 origine
  res.setHeader("Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy", "same-site");
```

Axios react :

```js
  var data = JSON.stringify({
    email: "testapi",
  });

  var config = {
    method: "get",
    url: "http://localhost:4000/api/auth",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    data: data,
  };

  axios(config)
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
```

[result for the api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9bO3.png)

Comment: what are you expecting?

Comment: my result for postman 

https://zupimages.net/up/22/39/29ix.png @chovy

Comment: What does `response.data` show in your axios result?

Comment: It's a bit bizarre that you're setting `content-type: application/json` for a GET request.  `Content-type` only applies to the body and there is no body with a GET request.  This makes me think you're using this to accomplish something that `axios()` doesn't do for a GET request.  Parameters with a GET request are encoded into the URL as query parameters.  Have you done debugging on your server to see that you are getting the exact parameters with this request that you expect?

Comment: What does the POSTMAN request look like that works?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [req.query and req.param in ExpressJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18524125/req-query-and-req-param-in-expressjs)